# Reading string from C# managed code to C++ wchar* [] getting AccessViolation

Tags: c#, managed, wchar

The question is easy, Want to read a string from managed C# code to my unmanaged C++ code in `WCHAR* []`.
 The C function is:

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl myfunc(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
```

and in C# I imported the DLL:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int myfunc(int argc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]  StringBuilder str);
```

I run, but when I tried to read the string in my C++ code I get `AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

What is the correct way to do this and vice versa (i.e. passing a string from C++ unmanaged to C# managed code)?

Help Appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The C# side should probably be using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Vlad is ritght. C function expects an array of pointers to WCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your C function expects an array of strings, and you're passing a single string instead.

I haven't used P/Invoke myself, but this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069185/marshall-char-to-string-problem-calling-unmanaged-code-from-managed-code) might provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about C# to C++ but i can help you out in your C++ to C# problem.

Export the function from C++ code like this:

```
DllExport std::string MyFunction( std::string MyParameter) ;
```

This can be imported in your C# code as:

```
 [DllImport("DLLName.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public static extern string MyFunction([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string MyParameter);
```

Now, in your C# code the function "`MyFunction`" will take in a string and return a string. You can then call MyFunction and the operations can be carried out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `WCHAR*`, perhaps you should try marshalling as `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` instead to avoid passing half as much memory as expected?

The documentation on [Default Marshaling for Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.71).aspx) should provide you with more details.